# How to create deployed environment specific Ant build script

Tags: build.xml

I have a dbUser.properties file like below:

```
User_Dev=someuser1
Pass_Dev=pass1
User_Qa=someuser2
Pass_Qa=pass2
User_Prod=prodUser
Pass_Prod=pass3
```

Now I have to create a build file which will generate WAR file having dbUser.properties file as per environment, e.g.
In Dev properties file will be like,

```
User=someuser1
Pass=pass1
```

For QA,

```
User=someuser2
Pass=pass2
```

For Prod,

```
User=prodUser
Pass=pass3
```

My question is how I can write Build.xml in ANT?

Comment: Anyone can help pls?